# can the eigenvalues of a symmetric tensor be complex?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors

Let $T$ be a fully symmetric tensor of rank $3$ and size $N$.

Using the following definition of eigenvalues, let $x\in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{jk}^NT_{ijk}x_kx_j=\lambda x_i
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

With the constraint that $\sum_i x_i^2=1$.

In the literature it is said that the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors can be complex. I completely fail to see this. Here is my reasoning:

Since $T$ is fully symmetric, for all $i,j,k$ we have $T_{ijk}=T_{jki}=\dots=T_{kji}$. Let me define the matrix $M$ such that:
\begin{equation}
M_{ij}=\sum_k^N T_{ijk}x_k
\end{equation}
Due to the symmetry of $T$, my matrix $M$ is also symmetric and the first equation can now be written as:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j}^NM_{ij}x_j=\lambda x_i
\end{equation}
All $\lambda$ and all $x$ are real since $M$ is symmetric. Therefore $T$ cannot have complex eigenvalues.

Is this correct? if not, could we find a counter-example? (for $N=3$ or $4$ for example)

Comment: consider two cases real symmetric and complex symmetric

Comment: Sorry I meant that I only consider the case were $T$ has real components and is fully symmetric.